# Changing Host in LambdaEdge for an Origin-Request is forbidden

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have a very simple approach for a PoC:

```
export const handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request))
    // change Origin --> forbidden
    request.headers.host[0].value = 'picsum.photos';
    
    // uri change only works
    request.uri = '/200/300';
    // query change works too
    request.querystring = 'test=querystring';
    
    callback(null, request);
};
```

I need to change the host to a dynamic target. Like A/B-Testing.

The documentation [Lambda@Edge - Restrictions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-restrictions.html)
does not state, that the host is a read-only for Origin-Requests.

How can I solve this?

Changing only the URI and/or Query works fine and results in the correct origin request.